# How find this value if such $f[f(x,y),z]=f(z,xy)+z,x,y,z\in R$

Tags: functions

**Question:**

> let function $f(x,y)$ such
>   $$f(x,0)=1,x\in R$$
>   (2):$$f[f(x,y),z]=f(z,xy)+z,x,y,z\in R$$

Find the value
$$f(2014,6)+f(2016,6)=$$

My idea: let $y=0$, then
$$f(1,z)=f(z,0)+z=1+z$$
I think follow we can let $z=6$,But I can't solve it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

$f(y,z)=f(f(1,y-1),z)=f(z,y-1)+z$, so you have a reduction formula.  Repeat until you get to $f(k,0)$ for some $k$